# Elasticsearch Filtering on fields within a list

Tags: list, search, filter, elasticsearch

I am having trouble with filtering on fields within a list in Elastic Search.  I am indexing simple JSON objects for search and filtering.

An example object that is being indexed would be:

```
{ 
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "My Inventory",
    "description" : "This is a piece of inventory.",
    "sizes" : [ "big", "small" ],
    "geos" : [ { "country" : "US", "fullName" : "United States" } ]
}
```

I am able to filter by id, name, description, and size pretty easily, but when trying to filter on geo, I am hitting a brick wall.  Below is the filter I am trying to use.  I would be grateful for any kind of pointer to get me going in the right direction.  Thanks!

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/stuff/inventory/_search?pretty=true' -d '
    {
        "fields" : [ "name" ],
        "filter" : {
            "terms" : { "geos.country" : [ "US" ] }
        }
    }
'
```

Comment: did you use the right mapping? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-array-type.html

Comment: What do you get back? If the problem is that you get 0 results it might be because you indexed lowercased? Try with "us". Or if you used the defaukt mapping "us" is a stopword, thus it doesn't get indexed at all.

Comment: @javanna You were right.  I just used the default indexing for all fields except the ones I am sorting on, but using lower case worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, string fields are analyzed ("broken down into searchable terms" is how the [Elasticsearch docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html) describe it).  This doesn't work with a term filter, since a term filter does exact matching but the field will contain a possibly altered version.

You can tell Elasticsearch not to do that by setting `"index" : "not_analyzed"` in your mapping.  Your mapping for the geos field should look like

```
"geos" : { 
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "country" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
        "fullName" : { "type" : "string" } 
    } 
}
```

You may want to set fullName to `not_analyzed` also, depending on how you're going to use it.  If you want to use it with term queries or filters, it should not be analyzed; if you want to do fuzzy matching, spelling correction, etc, it should be analyzed.

Comment: Thanks.  Since the country code is just a single word, I was able to just lower-case the term filters.  This information would definitely be helpful if I were trying to term filter on the fullName field or other fields that use multiple terms.

Comment: Why did the default analyzer not work? is it because the country field is 2 characters, or a stop word.  I'm not quite clear on why the default analyzer didnt index the term "US".